# timestamp geojson with grouping feature layer control

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I want to visualize geo-data with timestamp information on it. I use plugins.TimestampedGeoJson in my python code to do that. the code is working actually but i need to display more than 1 feature in the map and each of these features can be shown/hidden from LayerControl.

is there any idea how to do that ?

#example with one feature

```
features_3 = []
for  row in DF_3.itertuples():
    long = row.longitude
    lat = row.latitude
    data= row.data

    features_3 .append (
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [long,lat],
            },
            "properties": {
                "time": str(row.xdate),
                "popup": "Record : " + str(data) ,
                "icon": "circle",
                "iconstyle": {
                    "fillColor": color_scale(data),
                    "fillOpacity": 0.6,
                    "stroke": "false",
                    "radius": 8,
                },
                "style": {"weight": 0},
            },
        }
    )

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features_3 },
    period="P1D",
    add_last_point=True,
    auto_play=True,
    loop=False,
    max_speed=1,
    loop_button=True,
    time_slider_drag_update=True,
    duration="P1D",
).add_to(map)
LayerControl().add_to(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

[TimestampedGeoJson duration parameter causes polygons to disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014444/timestampedgeojson-duration-parameter-causes-polygons-to-disappear)

The code in this link might help you. You can see how it's adding multiple polygon layers in the same map.

Comment: Please flag the question as duplicate.